# Updating specific attributes on models in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rake-task

I very new to rails 5 and need a hand with some syntax..

I have two models `Saving` and `Investment` .. Each Saving can have many Investments so the relation is 1:m. Both models have an boolean attribute `is_autobid`.

I want to create a rake task that retrieves all Savings where `is_autobid = true` and then updates the first investments of a particular Saving record to true .. so far I have:

```
task :update_autobids => :environment do

  Saving.where(is_autobid: 1).all.each do |s|

    investment = s.investments.first(:is_autobid, 0)
    investment.update(is_autobid = 1)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use update_column for updating single column it will not check for any validations and **you need to only update investment if any record is found**

```
Saving.where(is_autobid: 1).each do |s|
  investment = s.investments.find_by(is_autobid: 0)
  investment.update_column(:is_autobid, 1) if investment
end
```

> Update

If you want to load all records at once, than you can do it with below query

```
investments = Investment.includes(:saving).where("savings.id = (select id from savings where savings.is_autobid = 0 limit 1)").references(:saving)

investments.each do |investment|
  investment.update_column(:is_autobid, 1)
end
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the top answer thanks the rake task executed properly and the data updated accordingly in MySQL.

Comment: @Llanod11 Glad to know hear, i updated answer if you want more information please check it :)